# Maps of Middle-earth

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth, map

I am looking for a list* of maps of Middle-earth which appear only in JRR Tolkien's and CT's books and writings or were authorized by JRRT**.

From my reading so far I have:

*The Hobbit*:

- "Thror's Map"
- "Wilderland" showing west to the Ford, East to Lonely Mountain, North to Grey Mountains, and South to almost Dol Guldor

*The Lord of the Rings*:

- "A Part Of The Shire"
- "The West Of Middle-earth" and its four zoomed in panels
- topographical map of Gondor/Rohan/Mordor

---

* I know lists are sometimes frowned upon on SE, but this seems like a finite-sized non-polling Q/A. Yes, I also Googled for an answer but only found lists of non-canonical maps.

** I don't want to spark a canonical debate so I've changed the question. Plus this is really what I'm interested in.

Comment: +1 for considering the finite and non-open nature of your list question before asking. :)

Comment: https://tai.tolkienists.org/t/maps/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can still add:

***The Art of The Hobbit***:

- Thror's Map. Copied by Bilbo Baggins
- Map of the Misty Mountains and the upper part of the Great River
- Map of the Lonely Mountain and surrounding lands
- Plans of the Lonely Mountain
- *The Lonely Moutain* and map of the Long Lake
- *Wlderland*, earlier version

***The Shaping of Middle-earth***:

- the First 'Silmarillion' Map
- 'The Westward Extension'
- 'The Eastward Extension'
- 'Diagram I-III': Diagrams of the World
- Map IV: Arda in Valian Year 500, after the fall of the lamps
- Map V: [Arda] After the War of the Gods

***The Lost Road***:

- Chasm of Ilmen I,II
- The Second 'Silmarillion' Map (that's a really good one)

***The Return of the Shadow***:

- older Map of the Shire
- Plan of Bree
- The earliest map of the lands south of the Map of Wilderland in *The Hobbit*

***The Treason of Isengard***:

- The First Map of The Lord of the Rings (Maps I, Ia, II, IIIa, III, IVa-e)
- (Sketch-plan of the scene of the Breaking of the Fellowship)

***The War of the Ring***:

- Frodo's Journey to the Morannon
- Minas Morghul and the Cross-roads
- Plan of Shelob's lair (1)
- Plan of Shelob's Lair (2)
- Harrowdale
- The White Mountains and South Gondor
- Minas Tirith and Mindolluin
- Plan of Minas Tirith
- The Second Map (West)
- The Second Map (East)

***The Silmarillion***:

- Map of Beleriand and the Lands to the North
- The Realms of the Noldor and the Sindar

***Unfinished Tales***:

- Map of Númenor

***The Children of Húrin***:

- Simplified map of Beleriand

Pictures:

Map V of Arda:
[image: Original and Colorised Map V]

Plan of the Lonely Mountain:
[image: Plan of the Lonely Moutain]

Early Map of Wilderland:
[image: Early Map of Wilderland]

Second Silmarillion Map:
[image: 2nd Silmarillion Map]

Answer (score 7):

Aside from those published in Tolkien's books during his lifetime, which you've already covered, the Pauline Baynes map of Middle-earth may also be considered canon. It was certainly devised in consultation with JRRT and contains many names and places that didn't appear on the original LotR map and can only have come from explicit direction by Tolkien himself.

From [Michael Martinez's](https://middle-earth.xenite.org/2011/09/30/are-the-maps-at-the-beginning-of-each-lotr-book-hand-drawn-by-tolkien/) site:

> The only map that Tolkien himself specifically sanctioned and assisted with was the 1969 Pauline Baynes map of Middle-earth, which introduced several new place names (and at least one mis-spelling) into the Middle-earth lexicon. The Pauline Baynes map is the only non-Tolkien illustration used as an authoritative reference by Tolkien researchers when discussing Middle-earth as Tolkien himself published it.

The Silmarillion map may or may not be considered canon; while it was certainly based on JRRT's working maps, and being drawn by CT, not JRRT is not relevant here (CT drew the published LotR maps after all, even those originals from 1954/55), it may be argued that it doesn't necessarily represent JRRT's final chosen form, as he died before he could achieve that himself.  Discussion of that is not appropriate for this site, however, and you're better off going to a dedicated Tolkien forum.

On the whole, the topic of Tolkien canon is a fairly messy one with strong opinions held on all sides, so again, a dedicated forum is a better place to continue that line of enquiry if you wish to do so.

Comment: the first link doesn't work for me :(

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Maybe you could edit the post?