# What's outside of Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, middle-earth, arda

I wonder who lives outside of Middle-earth and what is their life like?
What are the names of the continents? Is there a big good map of Arda?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Middle Earth JRRT and CT maps](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/34747/21599)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Earth which is known as Arda in the Lord of the Rings has a few continents.  The stories mainly take place on Middle Earth, but there is also The Dark Lands, and Aman which is also known as the Undying Lands.

According to the LOTR Wikia..

> Not much is known about this continent, except that it formed during
>   Morgoth's marring of the world by breaking away from the main part of
>   Middle-earth (Endor). No Elves or Dwarves lived there, but it is
>   possible that wild Men may have lived there at some point. The
>   Númenóreans probably visited it on their long journeys, although it is
>   not known if they established dwellings there. Most of the continent
>   is covered by vast dense forests bordering much of its shorelines.
>
> The Atlas of Middle-earth pgs. 5 & 39

The Undying Lands is actually the place that most Elves and Ainur live.

It is to the west of Middle Earth.

In the wikia it states..

> The Undying Lands were a realm inhabited by Ainur and Elves. The area
>   included the continent of Aman and the island of Tol Eressëa. The
>   ocean Belegaer separated the Undying Lands from the western shores of
>   Middle-earth.

The history also states that

> Originally, mortals were allowed to trade with those from Valinor in
>   the Undying Lands, but were forbidden to sail west beyond the sight of
>   Númenor. However, in SA 3319 (Second Age), the treacherous Sauron
>   deceived Ar-Pharazôn, the last King of Númenor, to believe that the
>   ruler of the Undying Lands would be granted immortality and persuaded
>   him that this was man's right and he had but to claim it. To prevent
>   the king's invasion, Ilúvatar destroyed Númenor beneath the ocean and
>   set the Undying Lands forever beyond the reach of mortal Men. Elves
>   were still permitted to sail across the sea to the Undying Lands, if
>   they chose to (which most did).
>
> The Silmarillion

Here is a depiction of what The Undying Lands and Middle Earth look like on a map

[image]

Just to be clear the above post is not a "canon" map but a depiction of what it's supposed to look like... from the research I have done there are no canon maps depicting places other than Middle Earth... the closest thing canon wise is.. which is pre-LOTR as well...

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid that I have to -1 this for a David Day map, particularly since an actual Tolkien map (which looks nothing like this one) is available on the linked duplicates.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't believe there are any legit tolkien maps that show the undying lands and middle earth... I could be wrong though

Comment: The maps printed in History of Middle-earth 4 are legit and by Tolkien.

Comment: I haven't read them but I would love to get my hands on them... Were they actually drawn by Tolkien himself or were the drawings renditions of what Tolkien thought the world looked like?  When I say there are no canon maps of the undying lands and middle earth I mean both on the same map... The canon maps I have seen were drawn by Christopher Tolkien and usually only featured Middle Earth.

Comment: The map you've now added to this answer contains Middle-earth and the Undying Lands, both on the same map, and was drawn by JRR Tolkien.  I'm not sure what your difficulty is here; the map exists (it is in fact one of the *only* ones that exist) and is clearly the exact kind of map you're talking about.

Comment: It was drawn pre LOTR so it's just a map of Arda and it doesn't state where each one is... so you can only sort of speculate what each one is... In fact if you research about Christopher Tolkien it states on his wiki... He had the task of interpreting his father's sometimes self-contradictory maps of Middle-earth in order to produce the versions used in the books, and he re-drew the main map in the late 1970s to clarify the lettering and correct some errors and omissions.

Comment: Can you clarify - are you talking about the region named "the north west of Middle-earth" on the LotR maps, rather than the continent of Middle-earth between the east and west continents?